# Is there any way to get your old Tiny Death Star back re installing the app

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

My Tiny Death Star started always crashing when you tried to open it yesterday. Thinking that I know they back up the current state online I deleted the app and re-installed it. It reset every and I am back to square one.

It only seems to have an option to connect to Facebook now and not Google's game service. I never connected it to facebook before.

Am I completely screwed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are. The game backup is connected to Facebook, not Google, so if you never connected to Facebook, nothing was being backed up. As far as I know, Google was just tracking achievement data.

Sorry... Perhaps this is your chance to reclaim several hours per day of free time. Escape while you have a chance!

Comment: Yeah support said the same thing. I know it was backing up though because if it would crash which it did often, when you reloaded some times it would give the option of local or online versions.